# Issue setting the start page for Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome

On the settings screen of Chrome (Version 64.0.3282.140) there is a section called "On start up". There are three radio buttons. I select "Open a specific page or set of pages". This is set to my home page (a local file). Sadly Chrome appears to ignore this request and starts up displaying a page with Google at the top and a variety of recently viewed pages underneath.

The home page works fine in as much as when I click the home button chrome does indeed open my desired page. But I can not seem to persuade Chrome to start up displaying this page. Is this a bug in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much thrashing around I finally discovered the issue. It seems that the failure to show the correct page on "start up" was due to chrome not being fully shut down. I had naively assumed that when you clicked the cross in the red circle that meant that you were "shutting down" Chrome - but I noticed that Chrome's menu was still at the top of the screen even after the window had disappeared. If I manually selected Chrome > Quit Google Chrome to force a proper shut down then it would finally show my desired start page when I started it again.